# Joining Events with options

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

Database Architecture Question

I've got following classes:

```
 public class Member
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Char Gender { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Option> Options { get; set; }
}
public class Option
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

Now i wonder how to reach my goal:

There should be Events, with options attached. Now a Member should have the possibility to "join" an Event and select some options.

That means options were attached to an event and members can be attached to an event with many options.

Example:

User A joins event "A" with options One and Two
User B joins event "A" just with option One

Any ideas / help for me?
I'm working with Fluent API, but have no idea about the Relationships i have to do

╔═══╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║   ║ EventID ║ Option1 ║ Option2 ║ Option3 ║ Option4 ║
╠═══╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║   ║ Event1  ║ Members ║ Members ║ Members ║ Members ║
╠═══╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║   ║ Event2  ║ Members ║ Members ║ Members ║ Members ║
╠═══╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║   ║ Event3  ║ Members ║ Members ║ Members ║ Members ║
╚═══╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╝

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (Formatted text, please. Not images.)

Comment: It seems you have a many-to-many-relationship. About how these are configured with fluent API, there should be plenty of tutorials out there.

Comment: I dont think its solved just with one m:m relation. How to configure the fluent api is not the problem. Maybe there is a better solution for the architecture